# Is it possible for a Telegram Bot to send any type of message without users trigger?

Tags: bots, telegram-bot, messenger

So I need my Telegram bot to ask a question from user (send any message of any possible type) without any initiation from a user. Is it possible? I cant find anything about this.

Comment: Not possible - the user must always start the conversation. You can provide links to open a chat with a bot, however.

Answer (score 3):

If the user interacted with your bot before you just need to use their user_id and send your message. You can't however send message to a user who has never interacted with your bot.

Answer (score 0):

Telegram BOT never can take an action before user interact with bot. because most of available method need "chat_id". if you dont have "chat_id", you can only run simple method like getMe, getUpdates,etc.